# How do I display just the top 5 highscores from my file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**This is the file with the scores:**

```
Ishaan - 72
Jack - 84
Bob - 23
Louis - 77
Arnav - 56
Ben - 48
Ted - 39
```

**So far I have sorted the file but I don't know how to display just the top 5 scores from the file.**

```
ScoresFile2 = "/Users/KADAM BOYS/Desktop/Ishaan's Folder/Homework (Year 10)/Computing/Mock Project/Scores.txt"
ScoresWithNames = []
with open(ScoresFile2) as file2:
    for line in file2:
        ScoresWithNames.append(line.strip())
ScoresWithNames.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(" - ")[-1]))
```

Comment: How about `print(ScoresWithNames[0:5])`?

Comment: BTW, you probably wanna change `x.split(" - ")[-1]` to `int(x.split(" - ")[-1])`, otherwise it's gonna be string comparison, where, for example `'123' < '14'`.

Comment: @goodvibration i've given him that in his previous question

Comment: @Joshua Varghese ..... How do I print each score with the names with a newline in between every score?

Comment: @goodvibration.....How do I print each score with the names with a newline in between every score?

Comment: @Ishaan added that, it is the correct thing you required?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also has the same answer as your previous question, but modified :

```
l = ['Ishaan - 72', 'Jack - 84', 'Bob - 23', 'Louis - 77']
[' - '.join(k for k in j[::-1]) for j in sorted([i.split(' - ')[::-1] for i in l],reverse = True,key=lambda x: int(x[0]))][:5]
```

So if your sorted list is `list1`:

```
top5 = list1[:5]
```

If you are using lambda:

```
ScoresWithNames.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(" - ")[-1]),reverse = True)
print(ScoresWithNames[:5])
```

---

Now if you want to print it with a new-line, you have two ways:

```
for i in top5:
    print(i)
```

or:

```
print('\n'.join(i for i in top5)) # or scoreswithnames
```

Comment: that one-liner list comprehension is unreadable. it's not pythonic and only serves to confuse beginners.

Comment: @gold_cy he understands that well. This question is a continuetion of his previous question :)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get the 5 highest scores is with [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) from [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

with open("data.txt") as f:
    counts = Counter()
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split(" - ")
        counts[name] += int(score)

    print(counts.most_common(5))
```

Output:

```
[('Jack', 84), ('Louis', 77), ('Ishaan', 72), ('Arnav', 56), ('Ben', 48)]
```

If you want your scores formatted back into `"name - score"` format:

```
print([f"{name} - {score}" for name, score in counts.most_common(5)])
# ['Jack - 84', 'Louis - 77', 'Ishaan - 72', 'Arnav - 56', 'Ben - 48']
```

Comment: is it nessesary when the OP has a sorted list?

Comment: this is the continueation of Op's previous question :)

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Probably not, just another way of doing it with built in libraries from scratch :-). I didn't know this was a continuation.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b85f4ec45a5d63188ee3866bd55eb29fdec7fbf/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L575) also sorts.